# Error in looking for Action with Parameters from View upon submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having the following piece of code and i'm surprised that it's giving me error message:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

```
  public ActionResult CreateEmployee(int ID, string Name)
    {
        Employee model = new Employee(ID, Name);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee model)
    {
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Tasks");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", e.Message);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
public ActionResult Tasks(int ID, string Name)
    {
        EmployeeListModel model = new EmployeeListModel(ID, projectName);
        return View(model);
    }
```

View for CreateEmployee:

```
    @model MvcUI.Models.Employee

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.Partial("EmpDetails", Model)
 <p>  <input type="submit" value="Save" /></p> 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. It looks like the Employee object doesn't have a parameterless constructor and yet you are using it as action parameter in your POST action:

```
public ActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee model)
```

The default model binder which is invoked to bind the Employee object from the POSTed request values cannot possibly know how to instantiate it. You could either provide a parameterless constructor to this object or write a custom model binder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Employee` class doesn't have a parameterless constructor defined.  You should define a parameterless constructor

```
public class Employee {

  //parameterless constructor
  public Employee() {

  }

  //your constructor
  public Employee(int id, string name) {

  }

}
```

The default model binder uses the parameterless constructor to instantiate your object in the `CurrentEmployee` action.  Otherwise it wouldn't know how to instantiate your object.

Alternatively you could create a custom model binder to create and bind your `Employee` object.